# Spring Boot application fails to run - spring.resources.cache-period were left unbound

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, axon, spring-boot-devtools

I'm having difficulties with my Spring Boot application which is not willing to run.

According to logs the reason of this situation is unbound spring.resources.cache-period property.
This property however is set in application.properties and compiler is even returning it's value.

I'll really appreciate if someone could lend me a hand with that issue.

**Logs**

[image: pom]

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.gft</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>app</name>
<description>Axon implementation for app project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <axon.version>3.2</axon.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <lombok.version>1.16.20</lombok.version>
    <assertj.version>3.9.1</assertj.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.5</jackson.version>
    <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
    <s.dev.tools.version>1.3.0.RELEASE</s.dev.tools.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Axon -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>axon-core</artifactId>
        <version>${axon.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${axon.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>axon-test</artifactId>
        <version>${axon.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>${assertj.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>${s.dev.tools.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Utilities -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.13</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <baseImage>java</baseImage>
                <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
                <!-- copy the service's jar file from target into the root directory of the image -->
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.company.app.appApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.properties**

[image: properties]

Comment: You are overriding the version of spring boot devtools. Please don't do that as it must match the version of Spring Boot you're using. I'd argue that a bunch of version overrides there are unnecessary/dangerous.

Comment: Suggest to share Configuration Java class. Hope you have used Configuration annotation, and NOT ConfigurationProperties

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just as @Stephane Nicoll suggested, I've changed spring-boot-devtools version to the one corresponding my Spring Boot version. This, along with deletion of previously provided *spring.resources.cache-period* property solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
You should remove the version to use spring-boot same version

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware of your user's global configuration file for devtools:
`~/.spring-boot-devtools.properties`

This might have deprecated values like the mentioned `spring.resources.cache-period` in it, that are no longer valid.

=> In my case, removing this old value solved the same error!

Also have a look at spring boot's documentation for the order of configurations:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files