# SpringBoot Application with Gradle fails with ./gradlew bootRun

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am running into an issue attempting to build an introductory application using SpringBoot.

I am using Gradle as my build management tool

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

    }   
}
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.4.RELEASE'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'sia'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

description = "taco-cloud"

bootJar {
    baseName = 'taco-cloud'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

repositories {
     mavenCentral()   
     maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
     maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version:'2.0.0.M3'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version:'2.0.0.M3'
    runtime group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-devtools', version:'2.0.0.M3'
    //providedRuntime group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testCompile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version:'2.0.0.M3') {
exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure that should cover most of the dependencies.  I have just a couple classes and a couple tests.

Driver

```
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package tacos;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class TacoCloudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TacoCloudApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package tacos;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController
{
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Driver Test

```
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package tacos;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
//import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

@SpringBootTest
public class TacoCloudApplicationTest {
    @Test 
    public void contextLoads() {

    }
}
```

Controller Test

```
package tacos;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.view;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(HomeController.class)
public class HomeControllerTest
{
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testHomePage() throws Exception
    {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(view().name("home"))
        .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Welcome to ...")));
    }
}
```

This should be a super simple application but I seem to have a missing dependency or some other issue where SpringApplication.run fails to happen.  I have looked at other posts that are similar but the solutions given don't make much sense.  The error I get from the test is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The error using ./gradlew bootRun is similar since the application context never loads.  Really confused as this was supposed to be a no-brainer intro exercise.  The original exercise is a maven build, so I am not sure if that makes any difference here.

Super stuck....

Comment: Did you setup connection properties to database?

Comment: There is no persistence needed or configured with this application.

Comment: @Rcordoval - That actually was a part of it, which is interesting.  I needed to add two additional imports:
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

Then I needed to annotate the TocoCloudApplication with:
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})

However, while the test passes, the application will not run using ./gradlew bootRun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Rcordoval and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724672/spring-boot-application-fails-to-run-spring-resources-cache-period-were-left-u) I was able to resolve the issues with both the test and the failure of the bootRun task.

I needed to address what autoconfigure is attempting.  This also is trying to configure a jdbc DB.  So I had to update the driver class as with a couple imports and a new annotation to exclude trying to configure the DB.

```
package tacos;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class TacoCloudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TacoCloudApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Finally, the linked post pointed me to the last issue of the bootRun task.  I simply removed the version from the build.gradle for spring-boot-devtools dependency.  Now the application boots in tomcat and tests pass.