# Application not getting start while Springboot Upgradation from 1.5 to 2.0.5.Release

Tags: spring, spring-boot

[image]

What is the possible reason behind this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot application fails to run - spring.resources.cache-period were left unbound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724672/spring-boot-application-fails-to-run-spring-resources-cache-period-were-left-u)

Comment: No, there is no any devtools dependency in my pom